# Environment file location for "docker service create --env-file"

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am pretty new to Docker, and this looks like a very simple question, that I do not seem to find an answer for, unless I am missing something obvious. I am creating a service using the following command:

```
docker service create --env-file host.env ...
```

The swarm consists of Windows nodes only, but it is possible Linux nodes will join in the future. Where do I put **host.env** file so I do not have to hardcode the path?

Comment: What is your environment? Local Docker? Docker Swarm?

Comment: Does Docker service not require a swarm?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. My mistake. Are you using some kind of CI/CD? I would store the `host.env` file right next to a docker compose file and the deploy everything with `docker stack deploy`. It is not possible out of the box to store the `.env' file similar to docker secrets or configs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use docker compose. But generally, the `host.env` should be in the directory you are executing `docker service create`.